# Gstreamer: How to change RTSP port?

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

I'm trying to create RTSP server by `test-mp4` usage from `gst-rtsp-server` example. 
The example works, but I need to change basic 8554 port to another.

I checked the `test-record.c` example, where we can see:

```
#define DEFAULT_RTSP_PORT "8554"
static char *port = (char *) DEFAULT_RTSP_PORT;
...
static GOptionEntry entries[] = {
  {"port", 'p', 0, G_OPTION_ARG_STRING, &port,
      "Port to listen on (default: " DEFAULT_RTSP_PORT ")", "PORT"},
  {NULL}
};

optctx = g_option_context_new ("<launch line> - Test RTSP Server, Launch\n\n"
      "Example: \"( decodebin name=depay0 ! autovideosink )\"");

g_option_context_add_main_entries (optctx, entries, NULL);
```

But finally I can't understand how to change the port in `test-mp4` example. I'll be appreciated if you tell me a way for the solution..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you update the hardcoded define of 8554 to another port and recompile it should work as you intend.

Comment: The app is build in a way that the port can be changed by passing a parameter `--port` or `-p` if I'm not mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution:
It's necessary to add these lines:

```
.....
char *port = (char *) argv[2]; //argv[<X>] is a port - an input argument
g_object_set (server, "service", port, NULL);
....
```